# Replace carousel indicators with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel and im trying to replace the indicators with circle images, whenever i do it the image appears but the indicator doesn't disappear, i want to move the indicators and keep the image as an indicator, and i want to move the indicators to the left, how can i do that? here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src=" http://placehold.it/140x100" alt="...">
</li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with this, If you need further assistance, comment bellow the answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .carousel-indicators{
            list-style: none;
        }
        .carousel-indicators li, .carousel-indicators li.active{
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: #fff;
            position: relative;
            margin: 10px;           
        }
        .carousel-indicators img{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;            
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src=" http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="..."></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"><img src=" http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="..."></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"><img src=" http://placehold.it/70x70" alt="..."></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
          1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
           2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src=" http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
           2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything except the white square background, where the indicator image should be.  My image won't show, for some reason. I used your CSS code and this `<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img src="assets/1.png"></li>` Any idea why it's not showing?

Comment: Is it working fine when you are using http://placehold.it/70x70 instead of "assets/1.png"?

Answer (score 0):

Change carousel indicators position from bottom to left using "`.carousel-indicators`" class

add this style at bottom of your css file.

```
 .carousel-indicators {
           text-align: left;
        left: inherit;
        width: 15px;
        top: 47%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 2%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```